# WPF Animation Package

Tags: wpf

Is there any website that sells pre-made animations for WPF that would use or start from to incorporate in our on application? I found [this one](http://grafile.com) but it's too limited and a lot of the icons / animations even say "coming soon 2010. But it's exactly like what I'm looking for.

If you happen to know of websites like this please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[PixelLab](http://thinkpixellab.com/) provide an open source [Bag of Tricks](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot) which contains a set of transitions which can be use to animate changing the content of a control, eg when switching between views.